# Perform method action based on duplicate values

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a table, which i am creating a method on, i want run on action based on duplicatie values from 2 fields.

For example:

I have `Table A` which contains these fields:

```
IncidentDescription
Identifier
```

Now i want to run a certain action in the method based on the following criteria:

If the `IncidentDescription` already exists in another row in the same table, but only if the `Identifier` is different. (So it doesn't run the action if only 1 line with the IncidentDescription exists)

How can i solve this? Is it possible to accomplish this in an `if statement`?
Or is there a possibility/is it better to run a "while select" query, and (if it exists) run a count method based on the count result (>1).

EDIT:

I am trying to create the query as following:

```
    select count (IncidentDescription) from TableA;
    {

// I am trying to convert the result, because it gives me the error: "Operand types are not compatible with the operator, i am not sure how to make this.
        serialCount = str2num(IncidentDescription);

    if (IncidentDescription > 1)
           //Action to go here;
    }
```

I will build in the Identifier later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code as a hint and modify it according to your requirements:

```
TableA  tableA;
TableA  tableAJoin;
;

select firstOnly tableA
    join tableAJoin
        where tableA.IncidentDescription == tableAJoin.IncidentDescription 
           && tableA.Identifier          != tableAJoin.Identifier;

if (tableA.RecId)
{
    info(strFmt("%1 - %2", tableA.Identifier, tableA.IncidentDescription));
    info(strFmt("%1 - %2", tableAJoin.Identifier, tableAJoin.IncidentDescription));
}
```

If you need this check for `displayOption` method on a form datasource (where tableA is a datasource name), then modify it as follows

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{
    TableA  tableACurrent;
    TableA  tableALocal;
    ;

    tableACurrent = _record;

    select firstOnly RecId from tableALocal
        where tableALocal.IncidentDescription == tableACurrent.IncidentDescription 
           && tableALocal.Identifier          != tableACurrent.Identifier;

    if (tableALocal.Identifier)
    {
        //record has dublicates
        ...
    }

    super(_record, _options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, when i add this code, as a method in my datasource as a displayoption, it is showing records that are all the same. Any ideas?